# Report a two-sample K-S statistic from two precomputed histograms

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, statistics

**Problem:**

Here I plot 2 datasets stored in textfiles (in list `dataset`) each containing 21.8 billion data points.  This makes the data too large to hold in memory as an array.  I am still able to graph them as histograms, but I'm unsure how to calculate their difference via a [2 sample KS test](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html).  This is because I cannot figure out how to access each histogram in the plt object.

**Example:**

Here is some code to generate dummy data:

```
mu = [100, 120]
sigma = 30
dataset = ['gsl_test_1.txt', 'gsl_test_2.txt']
for idx, file in enumerate(dataset):
    dist = np.random.normal(mu[idx], sigma, 10000)
    with open(file, 'w') as g:
        for s in dist:
            g.write('{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format('stuff', 'stuff', str(s)))
```

This generates my two histograms (made possible [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082402/how-to-build-or-precompute-a-histogram-from-a-file-too-large-for-memory)):

```
chunksize = 1000
dataset = ['gsl_test_1.txt', 'gsl_test_2.txt']
for fh in dataset:
    # find the min, max, line qty, for bins
    low = np.inf
    high = -np.inf

    loop = 0
    for chunk in pd.read_table(fh, header=None, chunksize=chunksize, delimiter='\t'):
        low = np.minimum(chunk.iloc[:, 2].min(), low)
        high = np.maximum(chunk.iloc[:, 2].max(), high)
        loop += 1
    lines = loop*chunksize

    nbins = math.ceil(math.sqrt(lines))   

    bin_edges = np.linspace(low, high, nbins + 1)
    total = np.zeros(nbins, np.int64)  # np.ndarray filled with np.uint32 zeros, CHANGED TO int64

    for chunk in pd.read_table(fh, header=None, chunksize=chunksize, delimiter='\t'):

        # compute bin counts over the 3rd column
        subtotal, e = np.histogram(chunk.iloc[:, 2], bins=bin_edges)  # np.ndarray filled with np.int64

        # accumulate bin counts over chunks
        total += subtotal


    plt.hist(bin_edges[:-1], bins=bin_edges, weights=total)
    plt.savefig('gsl_test_hist.svg')
```

**Question:**

Most [examples for KS-statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884668/two-sample-kolmogorov-smirnov-test-in-python-scipy) employ two arrays of raw data/observations/points/etc, but I don't have enough memory to use this approach. Per the example above, how can I access these precomputed bins (from `'gsl_test_1.txt'` and `'gsl_test_2.txt'` to compute the KS statistic between the two distributions?

**Bonus karma:**
Record the KS statistic and pvalue on the graph!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i cleaned up your code a bit. writing to `StringIO` so it's more streamline than writing to a file. set the default vibe w/ `seaborn` instead of `matplotlib` to make it look more modern. the `bins` thresholds should be the same for both samples if you want the stat test to line up.  i think if you iterate through and make the bins this way the whole thing may take way longer than it needs to.   `Counter` could be useful b/c you'll only have to loop through once...plus you'll be able to make the same bin size. converting floats to ints since you are binning them together. `from collections import Counter` then `C = Counter()` and `C[value] += 1`. you'll have a `dict` at the end where you can make the bins from the `list(C.keys())`. this would be good since your data is so gnarly.  also, you should see if there is a way to do `chunksize` with `numpy` instead of `pandas` b/c `numpy` is WAY faster at indexing.  try a `%timeit` for `DF.iloc[i,j]` and `ARRAY[i,j]` and you'll see what i mean. i wrote much of it a function to try making it more modular.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import StringIO
from scipy.stats import ks_2samp
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()

%matplotlib inline

#Added seaborn b/c it looks mo betta

mu = [100, 120]
sigma = 30

def write_random(file,mu,sigma=30):
    dist = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 10000)
    for i,s in enumerate(dist):
        file.write('{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format("label_A-%d" % i, "label_B-%d" % i, str(s)))
    return(file)

#Writing to StringIO instead of an actual file
gs1_test_1 = write_random(StringIO(),mu=100)
gs1_test_2 = write_random(StringIO(),mu=120)

chunksize = 1000

def make_hist(fh,ax):
    # find the min, max, line qty, for bins
    low = np.inf
    high = -np.inf

    loop = 0

    fh.seek(0)
    for chunk in pd.read_table(fh, header=None, chunksize=chunksize, sep='\t'):
        low = np.minimum(chunk.iloc[:, 2].min(), low) #btw, iloc is way slower than numpy array indexing
        high = np.maximum(chunk.iloc[:, 2].max(), high) #you might wanna import and do the chunks with numpy
        loop += 1
    lines = loop*chunksize

    nbins = math.ceil(math.sqrt(lines))   

    bin_edges = np.linspace(low, high, nbins + 1)
    total = np.zeros(nbins, np.int64)  # np.ndarray filled with np.uint32 zeros, CHANGED TO int64

    fh.seek(0)
    for chunk in pd.read_table(fh, header=None, chunksize=chunksize, delimiter='\t'):

        # compute bin counts over the 3rd column
        subtotal, e = np.histogram(chunk.iloc[:, 2], bins=bin_edges)  # np.ndarray filled with np.int64

        # accumulate bin counts over chunks
        total += subtotal

    plt.hist(bin_edges[:-1], bins=bin_edges, weights=total,axes=ax,alpha=0.5)

    return(ax,bin_edges,total)

#Make the plot canvas to write on to give it to the function
fig,ax = plt.subplots()

test_1_data = make_hist(gs1_test_1,ax)
test_2_data = make_hist(gs1_test_2,ax)

#test_1_data[1] == test_2_data[1] The bins should be the same if you're going try and compare them...
ax.set_title("ks: %f, p_in_the_v: %f" % ks_2samp(test_1_data[2], test_2_data[2]))
```

[image]

Comment: I believe the reported KS-statistic here is wrong. `ks_2sample`  works on raw samples, and you are passing the precomputed histograms, so the test actually operates on the frequencies on each bin. The OP's question asks specifically how to run K-S on precomputed histograms.